# What does "/" means in namespace attribute of package element in struts.xml?

Tags: java, struts

I'm new in struts so I what know the meaning of "/" in namespace of package.
i.e.
 when I put namespace as "/Home"

```
 <package name="base" namespace="/Home" extends="struts-default">
            <action name="HelloWorld" class="controller.HelloWorld">
                <result>/message.jsp</result>
            </action>
    </package>
```

and type this Url : "localhost:8080/Struts2Example/Home/HelloWorld.action" on browser , then page opens.

but when I change the namespace to "Home"  then it gives "Error : 404".

So what's this "/" means ?

Comment: Do you think we can see something at "localhost:8080"? I don't run tomcat. And the namespace is the root namespace. And is STRUTS, not struCts

Answer (score 1):

From Struts Manual `http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/j2ee101302/working_with_struts/f1_struts_ide/f1_strutsconfigactionmappings.html`

and here

```
http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/namespace-configuration.html
```

The request URI path which, when received by the Struts servlet action controller, invokes the action mapping. `The path name is a relative path and must include the forward slash (/).`

Answer (score 1):

Here's some 101 on name spaces.
 The first thing you need to keep in mind is that namespace is not a file path.

**Coming to what a namespace does:**
What happens is that when a user hits a request to access a struts web application, this url is splitted into hostname, port name, servlet context name, namespace (if any) and the struts action.

Ex. : localhost:8080/myapp/discountModule/getPrice.action

Namespace divides the action configuration into logical modules.
For example if the URL /foo/myfoo/myfooaction.action is requested, the framework will first look for namespace /foo/myfoo. If the action does not exist at /foo/myfoo, the search will immediately fall back to the default namespace "". The framework will not parse the namespace into a series of "folders".

**So when do we use names Spaces**
Namespace is very useful in large web application that need to seprated into small domains or modules. Example lets say you are managing a shopping cart backend and this has 4 main section - ADMIN, ORDERS, SALES & REFUNDS

As described earlier, namespace is defined inside the tag using namespace attribute. To define these four domain, four tag will be defined with their namespace specification as follows:

Ex - localhost:8080/shoppingCart/admin/doSomeAdmin.action

REMEBER - IT IS NOT MANADTORY TO USE A NAMESPACE.

Struts documentation has few more examples - http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/namespace-configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

Adding to user1428716 
only "/" define the root name space.

```
<package name="base" namespace="/e" extends="struts-default">
            <action name="HelloWorld" class="controller.HelloWorld">
                <result>/message.jsp</result>
            </action>
    </package>
```

root is : "`http://localhost:8080/Struts2Example/`"
so the url is "`http://localhost:8080/Struts2Example/HelloWorld.action`"

and when we mention `"/namespacename"` then it means `"~root/namespaceName/your.action"`